Mariadb Not fully Utilizes RAM
I have mariadb server with 32GB RAM, set innodb_buffer_pool_siz to 27GB but the actual usage of CPU is very high that's causing slow performance but it's only consume 10GB+ of RAM
enter image description here
How to make MariaDB fully utilize full buffer ?

Perhaps that isn't the cause of the high CPU.

this server is only for mariadb, no other processes

Yea.  But my point still stands.  Perhaps the high CPU load is not caused by low(-ish) RAM utilization.

Enable slow query log with explain. Hi CPU usage can also be insufficient table cache - look at show global status output to examine usage. If you have sufficient data, and a query load that uses it, solving the CPU problems will eventually make the memory more full.


InnoDB in MariaDB (or MySQL) uses only the portion of the buffer_pool that is needed.  If the dataset (on disk) is significantly less than 27GB, there is no need for the buffer_pool to be that large.  (It is OK for it to be larger than necessary.)
Corollary to the above:  There is no way to "make MariaDB fully utilize full buffer".
"Slow performance" usually comes for complex queries and/or lack of an adequate INDEX.
Do SHOW FULLPROCESSLIST; so you can see the worst which query is hogging the CPU.  Then provide that query and the relevant CREATE TABLE(s).  From that we can discuss how to speed up the query.
See also the SlowLog for discovering the "worst" query.

